# Program skipping over lines of input file

Tags: c, input, output

I have this program that is supposed to ask you for temperature, and then use that temperature in the Planck function. The wave lengths are in a file that is called "inputwave.dat" 
which looks like

```
500
1000
1500
2000
.
.
.
11500
12000
```

(interval of 500 up to 12,000. Each on its own line)

The problem I am having is it is only printing out for every other line.

so its like

```
"500 ....
1500 ....
2500 ....
3500 ...."
```

I want it to print out every line, where in my code is this happening I cant seem to find anything in there that would be causing it to skip a line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h>
double planck(double wave, double T);
int main()
{
  double wave,T;
  double result;
  int ni;
  char outfile[80];
  FILE *out,*in;
  in = fopen("inputwave.dat","r");
  printf("\nEnter the temperature in Kelvin > ");
  ni = scanf("%lf",&T);
  printf("\nEnter the name of the output file > ");
  ni = scanf("%s",outfile);
  if((out = fopen(outfile,"w")) == NULL)
  {
    printf("\nCannot open %s for writing\n",outfile);
    exit(1);
  }
  while(fscanf(in,"%lf",&wave) != EOF)
  {
    fscanf(in,"%d",&wave);
    result = planck(wave,T);
    fprintf(out,"%7.1f %e\n",wave,result);
  }
  fclose(out);
  return(0);
}
double planck(double wave, double T)
{
  static double p = 1.19106e+27;
  double p1;
  p1 = p/(pow(wave,5.0)*(exp(1.43879e+08/(wave*T)) - 1.0));
  return(p1);
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try this (i.e. do not call `fscanf` twice):

```
while(fscanf(in,"%lf",&wave) != EOF)
{
  result = planck(wave,T);
  fprintf(out,"%7.1f %e\n",wave,result);
}
```

After it let's correct checking of return value of `fscanf`. This function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. So, body of this `while` should be executed only if this return value is exactly 1. So, it is better to change check:

```
while(fscanf(in,"%lf",&wave) == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `fscanf` twice . And this line -

```
 fscanf(in,"%d",&wave); // passing wrong argument to printf %d expects a integer you pass a double
```

Try this -

```
while(fscanf(in,"%lf",&wave)==1)
 {
    result = planck(wave,T);
    fprintf(out,"%7.1f %e\n",wave,result);
 }
```

Also you didn't close input file in your code .